# array_reverse не выполняет свою функцию

Tags: php

```
$url = "https://www.om1.ru/news/rss/";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = array_reverse(json_decode($json,TRUE));

print_r($array);
```

По логике **array_reverse** должен вернуть массив с элементами в обратном порядке, но на деле этого не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем заключается проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_reverse` правильно работает. У вас `json_decode` возвращает массив, в котором идет сначала `[@attributes]`, а потом `[channel]` и после выполнения функции `array_reverse` у вас `[@attributes]` окажется в конце.

И тут смотря что вам нужно перевернуть. Судя по структуре, вам нужно перевернуть `[item]` то есть элементы канала `"Последние новости"`.

Если это так, то нужно писать так:

```
$url = "https://www.om1.ru/news/rss/";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
//Обращаемся к `channel`, а потом к `item` и в итоге мы получим
//массив новостей, который потом переворачиваем
$array = array_reverse($data['channel']['item']);
print_r($array);
```